# How can I manage multiple versions of Scala & SBT in my dev environment?

Tags: scala, sbt

I just finished the awesome Coursera Scala course and am eager to continue learning more about Scala by exploring some existing open source projects. I've hit a snag while trying to get some of them running locally, though.

I come from a background in Ruby, where we use tools such as `rvm` or `rbenv` to manage multiple Ruby interpreters/versions on one system. What is the approach that Scala users take for working with projects that use different versions of Scala/SBT?

I suspect that I'm missing something big since this doesn't seem to be a popular issue.

Please note that I'm pretty new to the world of Java and the JVM in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at paulp's [excellent sbt-extras script](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras). This will enable you to pick which version of sbt you want to use on a per-project basis, and sbt will allow you to pick which version(s) of Scala you want on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 4):

I always use the latest `sbt` from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (OS X) and then control the Scala version and libraries from within the `build.sbt`.

Comment: Notice also that you can (and should) set the version of sbt used for a project in `project/build.properties`. Your native sbt is used to build that one, that's used for the project.

Comment: I got downvoted on this answer. Please tell me if there is a reason - I do think it answers the original question appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

More recently (Dec. 2016), you can try and check out [**sdkman.io**](http://sdkman.io/), The **Software Development Kit Manager**.

It is a tool for managing parallel versions of multiple Software Development Kits on most Unix based systems. It provides a convenient Command Line Interface (CLI) and API for installing, switching, removing and listing Candidates.

It installs Software Development Kits for the JVM such as Java, Groovy, Scala, Kotlin and Ceylon. Activator, Ant, Gradle, Grails, Maven, SBT, Spring Boot, Vert.x and many others also supported.