# Install scala 2.10.6 and 2.11.8 at the same time

Tags: scala, version, versioning

I need to have both scala versions on my mac at the same time. In ruby you would use something like chruby or rvm or rbenv. How can I get this functionality is scala?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I manage multiple versions of Scala && SBT in my dev environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13422189/432903), suggestions - [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras#sample-usage), http://sdkman.io/sdks.html

Comment: oh hey. dope. yea you can close this